# Posting an SSCCE that is multiple classes

Tags: discussion, support, posting

OK I have an answer to a question that takes the form of an SSCCE that is a little lacking in the first S, lol. There really is no way to reduce it without destroying clarity.

Specifically it is composed of two modules (just folders) which have two applications which demonstrate a  somewhat complex bug(?) issue with JavaFX. It is not a "what is wrong with my code ?" type question (I don't thinik !!). Instead it demonstrates a bug or subtlety in JavaFX.

The sum total of classes is only 8, three in one module and five in another. But it seems too big for a post. I am not sure how to proceed. I don't want to do something that is against etiquette.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed? Does SO have anything like small code hosting for a situation like this?

Thank you so much !

Comment: There is no such code hosting from Stack. My main theory (I don't know JavaFX so it might be slightly off), is that there is a way to isolate the behavior that is problematic more, without the use of these 8 classes. Is every line, in every class, 100% necessary to produce the bug?

Comment: yeah it really is. Running them all into a single class would not reduce the number of lines of code . It requires debug output, implementors of interfaces. One of the demos is 3 classes. The other is 5. They're all short classes, but the way Java is, yeah, it's gotta be classes or the app is unreadable garbage :(Thanks for taking the time to answer me !!!

Comment: hmmm, that feels very unlikely that it's all needed. But again, JavaFX is not something I know, so I couldn't say if it makes sense there or not. The one thing I will say is if that is **truly** minimal, as in every single line is required, and removing them would alter the result... then posting all of it in a question is appropriate. Will make for a wall of text, and part of me still feels like it should be possible to minimize it, but I'll defer to you, since it's your project and program :p

Comment: yeah a wall for sure. I am joining mailing lists and other groups where this kind of thing is more appropriate. Since the question has some interrest to some SO members, if and when I get a response or ultimately, post a bug report to Oracle, I will update the question with that information and links. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: File a bug report instead, wait for it to be accepted, then link to it in the answer? ...

Comment: By the way, do you want to post a question or an answer?